# Built-in WebDAV client able to connect via HTTPS with client certificate?

Tags: ssl, http, webdav

Using Mac OS 10.6.8, I'm trying to connect via HTTPS to a WebDAV server that requires client certificates. Without luck so far. The certificate is stored in the keychain.
Is this possible with the built-in WebDAV client?

Are there alternatives that integrate somewhat smoothly?

Comment: I know it supports HTTPS, but not sure about client certificates. There is [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/mac/index.html), which has many advanced features (including caching for much better performance), maybe give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1515454?start=0&tstart=0) on the apple discussion board suggests that it is not possible through Finder, but works in Firefox.